# How to assign a usb device to a program

Tags: drivers, usb

Im̀ new on Ubuntu 20.04. I switched recently and I'm installing some stuff from windows. I use an Pickit 3 programmer with he Pickit 3 Programmer interface. I installed it succefully through winehq. But the problem is that the Pickit 3 doesn't recognize my Pickit 3 USB programmer. But Ubuntu does! Here are some information that i founded online.

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c8:0238 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04d8:900a Microchip Technology, Inc. PICkit3
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub``
```

And this is the information that `lsusb -v` shows

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04d8:900a Microchip Technology, Inc. PICkit3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04d8 Microchip Technology, Inc.
  idProduct          0x900a PICkit3
  bcdDevice            0.02
  iManufacturer           1 Microchip Technology Inc.
  iProduct                2 PICkit 3
  iSerial                 3 BUR124209786
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      29
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Any ideas of how can I guide my PICkit 3 programmer interface to understand that there is an PICkit 3 controller plugged in?